# How to hide if select model is empty (nothing been selected)

Tags: angularjs

**FYI:** My angular braces are

```
<% %>
```

I have the following html:

```
<div class="modal-body">

    <div class="form-group"> 

        <label for="UserID">User</label>

        <select ng-model="SelectedUser" ng-change="ChangedUserSelection()" name="UserID" id="user-selector" >

            <option ng-repeat="item in Users" value="<%item.id%>"><%item.first_name%> <%item.last_name%></option>

        </select>

    </div><br />

    <div class="privilege-options" ng-if="SelectedUser != null" >
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to hide `privilege-options` if the select box does not have anything selected. How do I do this?

Comment: ng-if="!SelectedUser"

Comment: @Ved - Thanks man, wanna put it as an answer?

Comment: it is pleasure.. Posted as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your issue:

**Change**:

```
ng-if="SelectedUser != null"`<br>
```

**To**:

```
ng-if="!SelectedUser"
```